# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to get the largest palindrome is a string representation of a number?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, linq

I'm trying to get the largest palindrome that can be formed by `k` replacements of digits in the string `number`.

e.g.

```
number="3943",k=1 --> "3993"
```

For that exact test case I am getting `"393"` and for some test cases I am getting an error like

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence
>   contains no elements   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[TSource]
>   (IEnumerable`1 source) <0x414ec920 + 0x001ab> in :0 
>   at Solution.LargestPalindrome (System.String numstr, Int32 k)
>   [0x00197] in solution.cs:74    at
>   Solution+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.String str)
>   [0x00009] in solution.cs:61

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{
    static bool IsPalindrome(string s)
    {
        // returns true or false depending on whether the string
        // s is a palindrome
        // e.g. "abba" --> true, "acba" --> false
        for(int i = 0, j = s.Length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j)
        {
            if(s[i] != s[j])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static string Replace(string s, int i, char c)
    {
        // returns a copy of s with the character at index i
        // replaced by character c
        // e.g. "george",2,"x" --> "gexrge"
        string part1 = s.Length > 0 ? s.Substring(0, i) : string.Empty;
        string part2 = i < (s.Length - 1) ? c.ToString() : string.Empty;
        string part3 = (i + 1) < (s.Length - 1) ? s.Substring(i + 1, s.Length - i - 1) : string.Empty;
        return part1 + part2 + part3;
    }

    static string LargestPalindrome(string numstr, int k)
    {
        // numstr: string representation of number
        // k: maximum number of digit replacements allowed

        // if no digit replacements allowed, return same string
        if(k == 0)
            return numstr;

        // digrange will be {'0', '1', ..., '9'}
        List<char> digrange = new List<char>();
        for(char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
            digrange.Add(c);

        // possibilities will be all possibilities of replacing one digit from numstr
        // e.g. numstr="02" --> possibilities={"12","22","32",...,"92","00","01","03","09"}
        List<string> possibilities = new List<string>();        
        for(int i = 0; i < numstr.Length; ++i)
        {         
            foreach(char dig in digrange.Where(d => d != numstr[i]))
            {
                possibilities.Add(Replace(numstr,i,dig));
            }
        }

        // if k = 1, get all the strings in cumulativePossiblities that are palindromes; 
        // else, transform each into the largest palindrome formed by k - 1 character
        // replacements of itself
        var cumulativePossibilities =  k == 1 
            ? possibilities.Where(str => IsPalindrome(str))
            : possibilities.Select(str => LargestPalindrome(str, k - 1)).Where(str => IsPalindrome(str));

        // sort cumulativePossibilities in ascending order of the integer representation
        // of the strings
        cumulativePossibilities.ToList().Sort((s1,s2) => {
            Int64 i1 = Int64.Parse(s1),
                  i2 = Int64.Parse(s2);
            return (i1 > i2) ? 1 : ((i1 == i2) ? 0 : -1);
        });

        // get the last element of the now-sorted cumulativePossibilities, 
        // which will be the largest number represented by the possible strings
        // or will be null if there are none
        string largest = cumulativePossibilities.Last();

        // return the largest or "-1" if there were none
        return largest != null ? largest : "-1";
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string[] tokens_n = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_n[1]);
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        // use brute force algorithm to find largest palindrome of the string
        // representation of the number after k replacements of characters
        Console.WriteLine(LargestPalindrome(number,k));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good SO question, posting a wall of code and hoping that someone will debug it. Did you try to debug it? You said you have multiple test case with wrong results...did you debug and stepped through your code to see what happens and where it went wrong? If not, please try this first. If you did, what did you find out? This information could narrow the question and help us to help you.

Comment: I guess the exceptoin is raised (as the stacktrace says) at the line below the comment `// or will be null if there are none`....`Last()` does not return `null`, it throws exactly that exception if the sequence is empty. Maybe you want `LastOrDefault()`, but that's probably only a symptom, not the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient method, but simple to implement; the key feature is using `PalindromeSubstitutions` (counting *how many* characters' substitutions prevents string from being palindrome) instead of `IsPalindrome` (*just a fact* if string is palindrome or not)

```
// How many characters should be substituted in order to
// turn the string into palindrom
private static int PalindromeSubstitutions(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return 0;

  int result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length / 2; ++i)
    if (value[i] != value[value.Length - 1 - i])
      result += 1;

  return result;
}

// Let's test all substrings of size Length, Length - 1, ... , 2, 1
// until we find substring with required tolerance
private static string BestPalindromeSubstitutions(string value, int tolerance) {
  for (int size = value.Length; size >= 1; --size)
    for (int start = 0; start <= value.Length - size; ++start)
      if (PalindromeSubstitutions(value.Substring(start, size)) <= tolerance)
        return value.Substring(start, size);

  return "";
}

private static string SubstituteToPalindrome(string value) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    return value;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value);

  for (int i = 0; i < value.Length / 2; ++i) 
    sb[value.Length - 1 - i] = sb[i];

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Test:

```
 string input = "73943";
 string best = BestPalindromeSubstitutions(input, 1);
 string report = 
   string.Format("Best palindrome {0} -> {1}", best, SubstituteToPalindrome(best));
```

Output

```
   Best palindrome 3943 -> 3993
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a quite simple example of greedy algorithm. let's first count how many permutations are required (at minimum) to transform the number into palindrome.

```
int req = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= (s.length()-1)/2; i++){
    if (s[i] != s[s.length()-1-i] && i != s.length()-1-i) req++;
}
```

Now once it is done, let's go through digits from left to right once again: `i` goes through `0` to `(s.length()-1)/2` inclusive. Consider the following cases ( here `i` is not the middle letter, that case we consider separately) :

- `s[i] == s[s.length()-i-1]`, it wasn't counted in `req`, so if `k >= req + 2` and `s[i] != '9'`, we change both letters to `'9'`, and reduce `k` by 2, `req` remains unchanged. But note that we guaranteed that there are enough operations left to make sure that number can be turned into palindrome (if it was initially possible)
- `s[i] != s[s.length()-i-1]` - now if `k == req` or one of the letters is `'9'`, then do the following: `s[i]=s[s.length()-i-1]=max({s[i], s[s.length()-i-1]})`. Reduce both `k` and `req` by `1`.
- Now if `k > req` and both letters are not `'9'`, we change them both to `9`. `k -= 2`, `req -= 1`.

Now if `i = s.length()-i-1` and `k > 0`, change this letter `s[i]` to `'9'`.

The result u get at the end is what u are looking for.

Total complexity is `O(n)`.